# AWS DynamoDB data transfer (egress) pricing

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I found [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-data-transfer-prices-reduced/) regarding data transfer prices for certain services, but not including DynamoDB.

What is the rate for DynamoDB data transfer out?

Answer (score 0):

It is the same price as EC2, but this is only for when you are accessing DynamoDB from outside of that AWS region. If you want to verify, use the AWS calculator and do 1 GB/day of EC2 out data transfer and so the same for DynamoDB. It should be $1.40 for each.

Three examples where you might run into this charge are:

1. Apps in us-west-2 accessing a DynamoDB table in us-east-1.
2. Apps accessing a DynamoDB table over a VPN or dedicated link.
3. Accessing a DynamoDB table over the Internet. For obvious security purposes, this is likely not a good idea. If you are going to do it, really lock it down with IAM permissions!!!